# fluent nhibernate named-query without using hbm file for the map

Tags: nhibernate, dictionary, fluent, named-query

I am needing to create a named-query, and use it with one of the maps, that i currently have defined as a fluent map.

is it possible to continue using the fluent map, and be able to create the named-query dynamically in code? or, is switching to a hbm map the only option?

Answer (score 10):

Maybe I'm misreading the question, but you don't have to switch to hbm mapping completely.

You could continue to use fluent NHibernate to map classes and use hbm for named queries only. In your configuration, you'd then include the entities and the hbms.

```
_sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
.Mappings(m =>
{
   m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SomeEntityMap>();
   m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SomeEntityMap>();
})
.BuildSessionFactory();
```

In your namedQueries.hbm.xml you then only define named queries:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
<query name="Some.Query.Of.Yours">
<![CDATA[
          from SomeEntity e
          where  e.Property = :propertyValue
          ]]>
</query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Where does it look for the .hbm.xml file?

Comment: You have to define the .hbm.xml file as embedded resource. This line: m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SomeEntityMap>(); tells nhibernate at which project to look (SomeEntityMap need not be a map, rather any class which resides in the same project as the hbm.xml file)