# NHibernate left join select count in one-to-many relationship

Tags: nhibernate, join, count

I've been looking for a week after a correct synthax whithout success.

I have 2 classes :

```
public class ArtworkData
{
      public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
      public virtual string Name { get; set; }    
      public virtual IList<CommentData> Comments { get; set; }
}
public class CommentData
{
      public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
      public virtual string Text { get; set; }
      public virtual ProfileData Profile { get; set; }
      public virtual ArtworkData Artwork { get; set; }
      public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

I want to do this query :

```
    SELECT   this_.ArtworkId          as ArtworkId3_3_,
         this_.Name               as Name3_3_,
         this_.Description        as Descript3_3_3_,
    FROM     Artwork this_
         LEFT outer JOIN 
   (SELECT c.ArtworkIdFk, count(1) Cnt
   FROM Comment c
   GROUP BY c.ArtworkIdFk) as com
   on com.ArtworkIdFk = this_.ArtworkId
    ORDER BY 1 desc
```

But I don't find the way to.
At this moment I just have something like this :

```
ICriteria c = this.Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(ArtworkData));
if(filter.Category !=null)
{
      c.CreateAlias("Categories", "cat")
       .Add(Restrictions.Eq("cat.Id", filter.Category.Id));
}
DetachedCriteria crit = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(CommentData), "comment")
                    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                    .Add(Projections.Count("comment.Id").As("cnt"))    
                .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("comment.Artwork.Id")));                    



c.Add(Expression.Gt(Projections.SubQuery(crit), 0));
   c.AddOrder(Order.Desc(Projections.SubQuery(crit)));
```

But it's not what I want.
I want to get all Artworks order by the number of comments (but I don't need to get this number). 
Please help me! I'm going crazy!

Comment: Please edit the question instead of adding multiple answers that aren't answers.

Comment: (I merged your account - you should have ownership of this again now)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what are you trying to do with this weird SQL but if you need to get all Artworks with number of comments you can try this query:

```
<query name="ArtworkWithCommentsCount">
   SELECT artwork.Name, artwork.Comments.size
   FROM Artwork artwork
</query>
```

Comment: It doesn't mean that you are not able to define named queries in *.hbm.xml files

Comment: I don't know how get this result and merge with the other criteria. Is that easy?

Comment: Very simple - [fluent nhibernate named-query without using hbm file for the map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496915/fluent-nhibernate-named-query-without-using-hbm-file-for-the-map)

Answer (score 1):

If you use NHibernate 3 you could use this code:

```
var artworks = Session.Query<Artwork>().OrderBy(a => Comments.Count);
```

Or you could use HQL:

```
Session.CreateQuery("from Artwork a order by size(a.Comments)")
```

Comment: var artworks = Session.QueryOver<ArtworkData>().OrderBy(art => art.Comments.Count).Desc;                                    Once I created the Query, how can I use it?

Answer (score 1):

Try *Detached Criteria*. Take a look at this [blogpost](http://www.tunatoksoz.com/post/Querying-on-Child-Count-With-NHibernate.aspx).

Comment: Thanks gor, but I don't know which restriction I can use for the subquery. I can't use Greater than like in this example... Can I?

Comment: It is a projection. You can use `Criteria` without restriction.

Comment: I already have this : DetachedCriteria crit = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(CommentData), "comment")
                        .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                        .Add(Projections.Count("comment.Id").As("cnt"))
                        .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("comment.Artwork.Id")));              Now I want to add it to the main criteria, but I don't know how....